# how to configure Apache httpd.conf for x-forward logger

Tags: centos, load-balancing, httpd

I would like to configure my httpd.conf to see the client IP address and some more information.
this is what I have:

```
LogLevel warn

LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" proxy
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^.*\..*\..*\..*" forwarded`
CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined env=!forwarded
CustomLog "logs/access_log" proxy env=forwarded
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access_log combined env=!dontlog
```

all I can see when I do tail -f /var/log/httpd/access.log is:

```
combined
combined
```

all the time.
what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!
Dotan.

Answer (score 1):

`combined` isn't configured as a `LogFormat` in the configuration that you've provided - so instead of applying a `LogFormat` to the file, it's taking `combined` as a literal format string.

You'll need to set a `LogFormat` for `combined` for this to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Just install [mod_rpaf](http://www.stderr.net/apache/rpaf/), change the config file to allow your proxy's IP and you should get the clients' IP on your log files without making any changes to the log format.